# Removing scroll bar on videos on Facebook

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have a problem on my laptop when I try to view videos on Facebook. Whenever I click on a video to start it, `iframe` expands but not enough to cater the video and scroll bars appear.

There is a way to [fix](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/discuss/tpflop-remove-iframes-scrollbars.html) it by changing HTML i.e. by adding `scrolling="no"` to the `iframe` element. I tried it with FireBug and it works great, the problem is, of course, the fact that it isn't permanent. That's why I tried a [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) addon for Firefox but I believe it can only change CSS of a page.

Is there any other addon that can automatically add a scrolling parameter to every `iframe` on facebook page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed possible with CSS using Stylish or userChrome.css. Apply the following to the element that has scroll bars:

```
overflow: hidden !important;
```

Comment: I could swear I tried adding that with Stylish and it didn't work then. Indeed it works now! Just added `iframe{overflow: hidden !important;}` for Facebook page.